# Managing development between multiple SVN repositories

Tags: svn, version-control

I am working on a software development project that requires me to work in two different SVN repositories. The first repository is the client repository and the second repository is our internal development repository. I am trying to find the most effective way to manage development between the two repositories.

A little more information about the setup...

The client repository is the master. Multiple vendors work on development in separate branches in parallel. When a branch is complete, it is reintegrated into the trunk and all of the active branches merge up from the trunk. I may have 2-3 active branches in the client repository at a given time.

My development repository is the place where all of my team's development takes place. We don't use the client repository solely due to its lack of integration to our development tools for code review and task management. When a project starts, we export the source from the branch in the client repository and import it into our repository. This is where my question comes in...

What is the best way to manage development between the two repositories for a given branch? During the life of a project, there may be updates to our branch in the client repository that need to be pulled in to our repository. We also need to be able to send changes to our branch in the client repository for releases.

I've come up with two potential options thus far:

1. Use patches to manage the changes between branches. The downfall here is any tree structure changes won't be included.
2. Use svnrdump to replay the revisions between branches. The problem with this approach is I'm not sure if its the purpose of this tool and what would happen if a revision it replayed conflicted with changes we've made. The tool is primarily for migrating repositories.

SVN 1.7 is used for both servers.

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Frankly, this is a case where Subversion just doesn't have a good workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Join both repositories into one big "superrepo", using externals (master repo is empty, with real repo, mounted over externals definitions)

This way all transfers of revisions between repositories can be (TBT!) just ordinary merges